# Placing dialog fragment in the center of the Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-dialogfragment

I have this layout in my activity, and I want to add a dialog fragment to "`map_extras`", however, the dialog fragment doesn't place in the center of the screen. What I'm I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_extras"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the dialog fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="asdf1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="asdf2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="asdf3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do here? You show the first layout on the screen and place the second one as a Fragment in it? There are some things to consider/try:

- Is the first layout really filling the screen? Add a background color to verify.
- Your second layout has `wrap_content` as height and width, so it will be placed in the top left corner of its parent if not specified differently.
- Try to change `map_extras` to be a `FrameLayout` with `gravity=center` instead of a `RelativeLayout`
- You could also change the second layout size to `match_parent` and to the centering in there.